# Store instances of same class in a NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, instance

I'm creating a little game using Sprite-kit and i'm having problems trying to store an object which means an enemy in the game.I use the same strategy that i use in my C++ programs but with objective-C and pointers the strategy doesn't work.

```
enemigo *nemesis = [[enemigo alloc] init];
self.almacenEnemigos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:kNumEnemigos];

for(int i = 0; i < kNumEnemigos; i++)
{
    [nemesis pintarEnemigo:CGPointMake(20+5*i, 20+5*i)];
    [self.almacenEnemigos addObject:nemesis];
}
```

I want to create four enemies but at the end i only have four times the same memory address according to a unique enemy. The var `almacenEnemigos` is an class attribute in the SKScene class.

Comment: Yes, because you are adding the same `nemesis` instance variable into the array over and over again in the `for` loop. If you want four different enemies, you need 4 new objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only creating one instance of enemigo, there in your first line. You need to move the creation of the instances into the loop.

```
self.almacenEnemigos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:kNumEnemigos];

    for(int i = 0; i < kNumEnemigos; i++)
    {
        enemigo *nemesis = [[enemigo alloc] init];
        [nemesis pintarEnemigo:CGPointMake(20+5*i, 20+5*i)];
        [self.almacenEnemigos addObject:nemesis];
    }
```